# ASP.net AppendHeader not working in ASP MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, http-headers

I'm having problems getting AppendHeader to work properly if I am also using an authorize filter. I'm using an actionfilter for my AJAX actions that applies Expires, Last-Modified, Cache-Control and Pragma (though while testing I have tried including it in the action method itself with no change in results).

If I don't have an authorize filter the headers work fine. Once I add the filter the headers I tried to add get stripped.

The headers I want to add

```
Response.AppendHeader("Expires", "Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT");
Response.AppendHeader("Last-Modified", String.Format("{0:r}", DateTime.Now));
Response.AppendHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
Response.AppendHeader("Cache-Control", "post-check=0, pre-check=0");
Response.AppendHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
```

An example of the headers from a correct page:

```
Server ASP.NET Development Server/9.0.0.0
Date    Mon, 14 Jun 2010 17:22:24 GMT
X-AspNet-Version    2.0.50727
X-AspNetMvc-Version 2.0
Pragma  no-cache
Expires Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT
Last-Modified   Mon, 14 Jun 2010 18:22:24 GMT
Cache-Control   no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Content-Type    text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length  352
Connection  Close
```

And from an incorrect page:

```
Server  ASP.NET Development Server/9.0.0.0
Date    Mon, 14 Jun 2010 17:27:34 GMT
X-AspNet-Version    2.0.50727
X-AspNetMvc-Version 2.0
Pragma  no-cache, no-cache
Cache-Control   private, s-maxage=0
Content-Type    text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length  4937
Connection  Close
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To manage the output cache you can use [OutputCache](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dhananjaycoder/outputcachinginmvcapplication02222009222109PM/outputcachinginmvcapplication.aspx) attribute on your Action

EDIT

If you are looking to the AuthorizeAttribute source code, you will see it overrides the output cache policy and the reason is in comments in this code:

```
 if (AuthorizeCore(filterContext.HttpContext)) {
        // ** IMPORTANT **
        // Since we're performing authorization at the action level, the authorization code runs
        // after the output caching module. In the worst case this could allow an authorized user
        // to cause the page to be cached, then an unauthorized user would later be served the
        // cached page. We work around this by telling proxies not to cache the sensitive page,
        // then we hook our custom authorization code into the caching mechanism so that we have
        // the final say on whether a page should be served from the cache.

        HttpCachePolicyBase cachePolicy = filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache;
        cachePolicy.SetProxyMaxAge(new TimeSpan(0));
        cachePolicy.AddValidationCallback(CacheValidateHandler, null /* data */);

...
}
```

Comment: It worked, but why does using an authorize attribute override my use of headers when it worked fine without it?